# Can I add any object to Model in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I wanted to add a bean to model in Spring MVC Controller.  But, validator exception is thrown:

> Illegalstate exception.

Can anyone guide me to submit a form and display the content which I get after form submission? In this case, I need to use a bean to display all my information in view.

Like:

```
model.addAttribute("simple", new Student());
```

But, I am keep getting IllegaStateException from validator.

Download:

https://sites.google.com/site/jimjicky/SpringFormValidation.rar?attredirects=0&d=1

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

    private Map<Integer, Employee> emps = null;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("employeeValidator")
    private Validator validator;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    public EmployeeController() {
        emps = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("employee")
    public Employee createEmployeeModel() {
        // ModelAttribute value should be same as used in the empSave.jsp
        return new Employee();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("student")
    public Student createStudentModel() {
        // ModelAttribute value should be same as used in the empSave.jsp
        return new Student();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/emp/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String saveEmployeePage(Model model) {
        logger.info("Returning empSave.jsp page");
        return "empSave";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/emp/save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEmployeeAction(
            @ModelAttribute("employee") @Validated Employee employee,@ModelAttribute("student")Student student,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            logger.info("Returning empSave.jsp page");
            return "empSave";
        }
        logger.info("Returning empSaveSuccess.jsp page");
        model.addAttribute("emp", employee);
        model.addAttribute("student", createStudentModel());
        emps.put(employee.getId(), employee);
        return "empSaveSuccess";
    }
}
```

Validator:

```
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.journaldev.spring.form.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeFormValidator implements Validator {

    //which objects can be validated by this validator
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> paramClass) {
        return Employee.class.equals(paramClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "id", "id.required");

        Employee emp = (Employee) obj;
        if(emp.getId() <=0){
            errors.rejectValue("id", "negativeValue", new Object[]{"'id'"}, "id can't be negative");
        }

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "name.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "role", "role.required");
    }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [com.journaldev.spring.form.validator.EmployeeFormValidator@1625cd8]: com.journaldev.spring.form.model.Student@bd8550
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.assertValidators(DataBinder.java:495)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.setValidator(DataBinder.java:486)
    com.journaldev.spring.form.controllers.EmployeeController.initBinder(EmployeeController.java:38)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.InitBinderDataBinderFactory.initBinder(InitBinderDataBinderFactory.java:62)
    org.springframework.web.bind.support.DefaultDataBinderFactory.createBinder(DefaultDataBinderFactory.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.updateBindingResult(ModelFactory.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.updateModel(ModelFactory.java:206)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.getModelAndView(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:755)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Comment: can you paste in your stack error please, also your controller code please.

Comment: Add your validator code as well please

Comment: validator code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided try changing your InitBinder to following:

```
@InitBinder("employee")
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

The reason this works is because of the value provided, in this case the value being "employee".

```
public abstract String[] value

    The names of command/form attributes and/or request parameters that this init-binder method is supposed to apply to.
```

In your form you have multiple objects, without advising the @InitBinder what object to validate it attempted to validate your Student object as well, thus failing as it didn't meet the class requirements.

By specifying "employee" it basically ensured it only applied the validation against the Employee object.

Comment: Could you please tell me the reason. I didn't see this information any where in documentation.

Comment: I'll update answer with full explanation give me bit.